# error encoding characters when open in Microsoft office a Kingsoft Office document

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've a trouble with a document which I edited with Kingsoft Office in linux, the receiver told me than the document shows weird characters where instead of tildes like á é í

this is what she is seeing

[image]

Now, I've opened the same file in other computers with office 2010 started and also with office 2013, both computers display ok the document, also I tried changing the file format, practically I've used all formats availables in KOffice with the same result

my computer and the pc's where I opened the document are using english version of windows, I'm not sure but I think than the receiver is using some asian version, how could I fix this kind of errors?..thanks!